# Restrict access to the owner of an object in DDD

Tags: java, security, domain-driven-design, authorization

Let's say there is an object `TaskList` which can be edited and deleted only by its owner. Other users should only by able to take a task and update its status.

The following options come to my mind:

- check the ownership and access in the controller of the web application
- let the repository return proxy object which throws exception on certain operations, but the controller (or view) would still need to know which actions (in form of links or form fields) should be visible
- pass the caller (user) to the method of the domain object, so that the domain object can itself check whether the caller ist allowed or not.

The used technology is Java.

Any other/better ideas?

**Interesting articles about security and DDD**

- [Domain Object Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/reference/domain-acls.html) with the Spring framework
- [Security in Domain-Driven Design](http://www.utwente.nl/ewi/trese/graduation_projects/2008/Uithol.pdf)

I have accepted my own answer now, because that is what I actually use, but further suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it unnecessarily complex to create accessor classes for each protected domain class as suggested by 'Gray'. My solution is probably not perfect, but simple to use and - more important - robust. You cannot forget to use a certain object or to check conditions outside.

```
public class TaskList {

    private SystemUser owner;
    private List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

    public TastList(SystemUser owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public void Add(Task task) {
        Guard.allowFor(owner); 
        tasks.add(task);
    }
}
```

The `Guard` knows the current user (from a thread local for example) and compares it to the owner passed as parameter to `allowFor(owner)`. If access is denied a security exception will be thrown.

That is simple, robust and even easy to maintain since only the guard has to be changed if the underlying authentication changes.

Answer (score 3):

I would not encode the ownership/permissions model into the `TaskList` domain object.  That sort of business logic should be external.  I also don't like the idea of a proxy object.  Although it would certainly work, it would confuse debugging and is, in this case at least, unnecessarily complex.  I would also not check it in the controller.

Instead I would create a business logic object which oversees the permissions for `TaskList`.  So the `TaskList` would have an owner field but you would have at external accessor which would do the business logic.  Something like:

```
public class TaskListAccessor {
    private TaskList taskList;
    private User reader;

    public void updateStatus(Status status) {
        // everyone can do this
        taskList.updateStatus(status);
    }

    /** Return true if delete operation is allowed else false */
    public boolean isDeleteAllowed() {
        return taskList.getOwner().equals(reader);
    }

    /** Delete the task.  Only owners can do this.  Returns true if worked else false */
    public boolean delete() {
        if (isDeleteAllowed()) {
           taskList.delete();
           return true;
        } else {
           return false;
        }
    }
    // ... other accessors with other is*Allowed methods
}
```

If you need to require that all operations on `TaskList` objects go through accessors then you could create a factory class which is the only one who creates `TaskList` using package constructors or something.  Maybe the factory is the only one who would use the DAO to look up the `TaskList` from the data store.

However, if there are too many methods to control in this fashion then a proxy might be easier.  In both cases having `TaskList` be an interface would be recommended, with the implementation class hidden by the proxy or the accessor.